# How to filter objects with many to many relationships in django

Tags: python, django, database

I am new at Django and I am trying to discover many to many relationships.

I have a word model which has a many to many relationship with the default user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Word(models.Model):
    definition = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    turkish = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    english = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.english

    def summary(self):
        return self.definition[:50] + "..."
```

I have an example word object belonging to two users and I want only these two users to see this word object on their feedpage. How should I correct the view function below?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@login_required
def home(request):
    user = request.user 
    small = user.username.title()
    words = Word.objects.filter(??????) #order_by('-english')
    return render(request, 'intro.html', {'words': words, 'small' : small})
```

Basicly, I want to check if a word object's user list contains authourized user, and if it contains, the word will be taken from database. How can I code this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should just be able to do

```
words = Word.objects.filter(users=user)
```

And to check for several users, you could do things like

```
words = Word.objects.filter(users__in=[user1,user2])
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for examples.